# Entity Framework Core 1.1 In Memory Database fails adding new entities

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am using the following code in a unit test for the test setup:

```
var simpleEntity = new SimpleEntity();
var complexEntity = new ComplexEntity
{
    JoinEntity1List = new List<JoinEntity1>
    {
        new JoinEntity1
        {
            JoinEntity2List = new List<JoinEntity2>
            {
                new JoinEntity2
                {
                    SimpleEntity = simpleEntity
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
var anotherEntity = new AnotherEntity
{
    ComplexEntity = complexEntity1
};

using (var context = databaseFixture.GetContext())
{
    context.Add(anotherEntity);
    await context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

When SaveChangesAsync is reached EF throws an ArgumentException with the following message:

> An item with the same key has already been added. Key: 1

I'm using a fixture as well for the unit test class which populates the database with objects of the same types, though for this test I want this particular setup so I want to add these new entities to the in memory database. I've tried adding the entities on the DbSet (not the DbContext) and adding all three entities separatly to no avail. I can however add "simpleEntity" separately (because it is not added in the fixture) but EF complains as soon as I try to add "complexEntity" or "anotherEntity".

It seems like EF in memory database cannot handle several Add's over different instances of the context. Is there any workaround for this or am I doing something wrong in my setup?

The databaseFixture in this case is an instance of this class:

```
namespace Test.Shared.Fixture
{
    using Data.Access;
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

    public class InMemoryDatabaseFixture : IDatabaseFixture
    {
        private readonly DbContextOptions<MyContext> contextOptions;

        public InMemoryDatabaseFixture()
        {
            var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase()
            .BuildServiceProvider();

            var builder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<MyContext>();
            builder.UseInMemoryDatabase()
                   .UseInternalServiceProvider(serviceProvider);

            contextOptions = builder.Options;
        }

        public MyContext GetContext()
        {
            return new MyContext(contextOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does your model and context look like?

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this problem by using Collection Fixtures so you can *share* this fixture across several test classes. This way you don't build you context several times and thus you won't get this exception:

[Some information about collection Fixture](https://xunit.github.io/docs/shared-context.html)

My own example:

```
[CollectionDefinition("Database collection")]
public class DatabaseCollection : ICollectionFixture<DatabaseFixture>
{  }

[Collection("Database collection")]
public class GetCitiesCmdHandlerTests : IClassFixture<MapperFixture>
{
    private readonly TecCoreDbContext _context;
    private readonly IMapper _mapper;

    public GetCitiesCmdHandlerTests(DatabaseFixture dbFixture, MapperFixture mapFixture)
    {
        _context = dbFixture.Context;
        _mapper = mapFixture.Mapper;
    }

    [Theory]
    [MemberData(nameof(HandleTestData))]
    public async void Handle_ShouldReturnCountries_AccordingToRequest(
        GetCitiesCommand command,
        int expectedCount)
    {
        (...)
    }

    public static readonly IEnumerable<object[]> HandleTestData
        = new List<object[]>
        {
            (...)
        };
}
```

}

Good luck,
Seb